# Why do jQuery selectors sometimes not work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a very strange problem. Under some elusive circumstances I fail to apply any jQuery selector on my pages under IE. It's OK under Firefox though. The jQuery function simply returns empty array.

Any suggestions?

Page is too complex to post it here. Practically any selector, except `"#id"` selectors, returns a zero element array. The jQuery version is 1.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading to jQuery 1.2.6, you should be on the latest release of jQuery if you are having problems first ensure you are on the latest and greatest.

Answer (score 3):

What version(s) of IE is it failing under? Is it failing for a specific complex selector? I think we need an example.

Edit: Does the problem go away if you upgrade to 1.2.6? 1.2.6 is primarily a bug-fix release according to [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2.6).

Failing that, the best way to find the problem is to create a minimum page that can reproduce the bug. Without that, it's just about impossible to troubleshoot.